# Conditional RegEx character

Tags: regex, preg-replace, expression

How can I do a regex expression with a conditional character?

For example I have the following expression:

```
preg_replace(/\$[0-9]{1,10}|[0-9]{1,10}\$/, '', $content);
```

This replaces $9000 and 9000$.
Can I simplify that expression ? So that it will still replace the price if the $ character is at the begining or at the end of the number?

Comment: What you have is already simple and does what you want. I don't see how it can be made any simpler.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: But it will replace `9000` that's not preceded or followed by `$`, too. The OP only wants the replacement to be done in those two cases.

Comment: it can't be reduce further..

Comment: You could use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`: 2*3 chars saved :)

Comment: @sp00m, good idea. But can't be reduced? :( So if I have another want to filter out numbers with space after $ I need to add a third one? like this preg_replace('/\$[0-9]{1,10}|[0-9]{1,10}\$|\$[\s+][0-9]{1,10}/', '', $content);  ?

Comment: Do you just need to remove the $ (dollar sign)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have optional spaces between digits and `$`  sign:

```
preg_replace(/\$\s*[0-9]{1,10}\b|\b[0-9]{1,10}\s*\$/, '', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are using is already very simple and can hardly be simplified any further. But if, as your comment suggests, you have to add more alternatives to the pattern, you can do it like this:

```
(\$)?\d{1,10}(?(1)|\$)
```

This way, adding more alternatives is easy, as there's no need to add `\$<your pattern>|<your pattern>\$` for each alternative.

This is how it works:

```
(\$)? # capture a dollar sign in group 1, if possible
\d{1,10} # here comes your pattern, e.g. matching 1 to 10 digits
(?(1)|\$) # finally, a conditional statement:
          #     if group 1 captured something (a dollar sign in this case), match nothing.
          #     otherwise, match a dollar sign.
```

Adding alternatives is easy:

```
(\$)?
(?: # don't forget to enclose the alternatives in braces
    \d{1,10} # alternative 1
|
    [\s+]\d{1,10} # alternative 2
|
    # alternative 3 here, etc...
)
(?(1)|\$)
```

**However**, something like this is rarely necessary. Alternatives are only necessary if the alternatives are completely different from each other. The fact that your pattern captures dollar signs `$` indicates that the pattern is supposed to match numbers - and all numbers pretty much look the same. They may or may not be negative (aka preceded by a `-`), they may or may not be floating point numbers, they may or may not be whitespace between the number and the dollar sign, but it's still possible (and sensible) to make a regex pattern that captures all these, *without* using any alternatives:

```
(\$)?\s?[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?(1)|\s?\$)
```

This pattern is easily maintainable - e.g. if you feel the need to support thousands separators, you won't have to update the pattern in multiple places, as would be the case if you used alternatives.